# What is a word for someone who doesn’t want to improve themself

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word for someone who doesn’t want to improve

Comment: Recalcitrant, maybe?

Comment: I don’t think that quite embodies what I’m asking. I don’t think there’s a word for it

Comment: Welcome. I'm a bit confused as you ask for a word but your tag is "expressions". If you want a word, the tag should be single-word-requests. You can begin to type single-word.... and the autocomplete will make the tag pop up, which you can then click on.

Comment: It could also be *content*, *satisfied*, *happy*, *at peace*. For instance, somebody who is retired and just wants to enjoy life may not feel the need for further education, career advancement, or whatever else you have in mind. What does not wanting to improve oneself **mean** to you?

Comment: ***content***...

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by that.

If they don't want to because they're lazy, then try any of the following:

- [unambitious](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/unambitious?s=t)
- [ne'er-do-well](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ne-er-do-well?s=t)
- [indolent](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/indolent?s=t)
- [apathetic](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/apathetic?s=t)
- [feckless](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/feckless?s=t)
- rutterless
- languid

If their not wanting to is intentional, a pointed choice that they pursue, then try:

- defiant
- incorrigible
- oppositional

If their not wanting to improve or be better than they are is with extreme prejudice, you might try:

- evil
- bad
- malevolent
- nefarious

I'm sure there are other colors that one not wanting to improve themselves could take that I'm not thinking of, but these are the first few that come to mind.  I'd say the one that includes the greatest spectrum of meanings is "ne'er-do-well."

Answer (score 0):

You might consider:

1) Adjective: [Obstinate](https://www.google.com/search?q=obstinate&rlz=1C1CHWA_enUS614US614&oq=obstinate&aqs=chrome..69i57.2551j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

2) Phrase: Content with status quo.

3) [adament](http://adament)

4) [Complacent](https://www.google.com/search?q=complacent&oq=complacent&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l5.9023j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
Hope this was helpful.